# AJAX randomly returns response as NULL

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Here is the Widget i created - http://resources.bigrock.in/affiliate/widgets/Domain_Search_widget-300x250.html. It works fine and as expected ..mostly. The problem is, sometimes, randomly the Ajax response is null(i.e. 'data is null' is the error i get). I've been trying to figure the cause of this problem. Any help will greatly be appreciated.

and here are the contents of the PHP file

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
//header("Content-Type: text/javascript");

$domain_name = $_GET['domain_name'];
$tld = $_GET['tld'];

$text = file_get_contents("http://www.some.com/some.php?action=caajax&domain_name=$domain_name&tld=$tld");
echo $text;
```

earlier i was using "Content-Type: text/javascript" as you can see. But the occurrence of the error was much more. So i tried "Content-Type: application/json" while this greatly reduced the occurrence of the error it did not eliminate it.

I'm still learning a lot of these stuffs.. So any idea why this is happening??

Edit: 
On Codo's advice i studied the ajax profile using firebug. On a normal successful ajax call there  were-
params | headers | response | json

But on error there was - 
params | headers | rewponse | XML

here is the image - http://resources.bigrock.in/affiliate/widgets/img/error_headers.jpg

Comment: What if you change the Content-type to text?

Comment: Turn on Firebug, Fiddler or a similar tool and post the last request and the last response that lead to the error message. That will greatly help us diagnose the cause of the problem.

Comment: @cwallenpoole - as i said i used text/javascript earlier so i believe it supports content-type text as well.. right?? and that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Codo - ya thought of doing that, the think is i have error reporting code that notifies me .. when an error occurs but at the time i wasn't able to replicate the error. That said i shall try and capture the headers at the time of error and put them up here. But was also wondering can i capture it in my error reporting(ie the request\response\headers ??)

Comment: Does Anyone have a solution here??? I added the URL of the image which shows the Ajax request header info, in my original post. PLease someone HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not encoding your response as JSON.  Whatever you set in the header needs to be what you echo the content as.  Also, `text/javascript` isn't really a good header to use.  If you are just trying to echo out the html from that link, it should be `text/html`.

Here is the code for JSON:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
//header("Content-Type: text/javascript");

$domain_name = $_GET['domain_name'];
$tld = $_GET['tld'];

$text = file_get_contents("http://www.some.com/some.php?action=caajax&domain_name=$domain_name&tld=$tld");
echo json_encode($text);
```

Comment: Hey Kyle forgot to mention that the file some.php returned data in this format - {"dfasdasdasdsad.com":{"status":"available","classkey":"domcno"}} .. Does this need to be json encoded??

Comment: Oh, okay.  If that is what is echoed out, then it is "valid" json.  The only problem is that "dfasdasdasdsad.com" has a . in it, which will cause problems when trying to use the returned json object in javascript.  Would you post the piece of Javascript you use for the ajax call in your post, please?

Comment: Hey Kyle i cant add it here coz of the character limit - you can check it out on the above mentioned URL. And Inspect element(using firebug or equivalent) to see the ajax method used